# How to handle /topic and /app subscription with Spring WS Stomp

Tags: stomp, spring-rabbit, spring-ws

I'm using **Spring WS STOMP** to handle server to client notifications.
I'm using an external broker: RabbitMQ.

As far as I read, Spring forwards `/topic` messages to broker.
By other hand `/app` messages are handle directly from Spring Controller and the reply is sent just to the requester.

My js client has to subscribe to a notification service that inform the user about the status of a service.

The message broker sends the STOMP message for each status change.
But at the client subscription I need to initilize the information with the current status and to reply just to this client without involving the broker.
Then I tought `/topic/...` is the message for broadcasting the status change, and `/app/...` is the message to initialize the client status at client subscription without involving the broker.

This is my controller to reply with service status at subscription:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/servicestatus")
public Status subscriptionStatus() {
    return checkService.getStats();
}
```

This is the js code:

```
stompClient.subscribe("/app/servicestatus", function (msg) { alert("Status change: "+msg); });
```

This client subscription works only for the very first initialization, if the broker sends a status update, the client doesn't receive it.
Then I tried to switch it to topic:

```
stompClient.subscribe("/topic/servicestatus", function (msg) { alert("Status change: "+msg); });
```

Now it works for updates from broker, but it doesn't work at the client subscription because `@SubscribeMapping("/servicestatus")` is not reached.

What I'm missing? May I subscription to both `/topic/servicestatus` and `/app/servicestatus` with the same function?

I read this question: [Does Spring @SubscribeMapping really subscribe the client to some topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085791/does-spring-subscribemapping-really-subscribe-the-client-to-some-topic)
But I didn't find a clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution, I have to use `@MessageMapping` instead of `@SubscribeMapping` and add a `send` by js client command after subscription.

Server side:

```
@MessageMapping("/servicestatus")
public Status subscriptionStatus() {
    //this reply will be handled by stompClient.subscribe("/topic/servicestatus" callback function
    return checkService.getStats();
}
```

JS Client side:

```
stompClient.subscribe("/topic/servicestatus", function (msg) { alert("Status change: "+msg); });
stompClient.send("/app/servicestatus");
```